# Could not find main class...jar or manifest

Tags: java

I am very new to programming but I am trying to learn.  I have picked up quite a bit but some concepts just seem to go over my head.  It seems like when you are learning like me and you search for a problem, you get many many different answers.  Sometimes the way the answers are worded can but confusing to a beginner.  Anyway, here is my problem.

I have created a very simple program that will do a basic calculation of CMU blocks in a wall.  I used the JOptionPane instead of console.  I wrote the code in notepad, then saved it as a .java file (blocktestgui.java).  I then compiled it with the command "javac blocktestgui.java" to get the "bg.class" file.  I can run the program from cmd with "java bg" and it works great.  My real problem comes with the jar file.  I created a manifest.txt file with Main-Class: bg then an empty line following.  Then I use "jar cvmf manifest.txt CMU.jar bg.class" and I get a jar file.  Then whenever I run it (in cmd or double clicking) I get "Could not find main class" error.

Here is what I have:

My java file:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class bg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String firstNumber, secondNumber;
        double number1, number2, sum;

        firstNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "Enter wall length in decimal feet:", 
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        secondNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "Enter wall height in decimal feet:", 
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        number1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber);
        number2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumber);

        sum = (number1 * number2) / 0.88;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total Blocks are " + sum, 
                "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

My jar contains my bg.class file and this is what my manifest file looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_02 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: bg
```

I'm at a loss because my java file works but the jar doesn't.  Any help would be great.

Comment: If your main class is put under a package, provide its full absolute path to the class in `MANIFEST.MF`'s `Main-Class` entry. For example: if `Bg` class is under `com.test` package, the full path to the main class  is `com.test.Bg`

Comment: Rename your manifest.txt to manifest.mf and create your JAR again.

Answer (score 1):

1. By convention, Class names must start with an uppercase letter, change `bg` to `Bg`.
2. `Bg` must be public, thus change the type definition to `public class Bg`.
3. Try choosing a more descriptive type name, `Bg` doesn't tell me anything about the type it defines.

Comment: how about his file name being `blocktestgui.java`?

Comment: It's not strictly true that his `bg` class must be public. Not since JDK 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a few things going on but open up the jar and confirm the manifest is called manifest.mf (not .txt) and that it is in a META-INF directory.  Jars are more or less zip files so if you are having trouble opening it just add a .zip extension for a quick and dirty way to access it (rename it back when done).

Comment: Yes, I extracted the contents of the jar and it is indeed a file called "MANIFEST.MF"

Answer (score 0):

It's a 'rule' of java that the class name and the source file name must be the same (so `class bg` should be in a file name `bg.java`.  You haven't done it this way.

BTW, I can't figure out how you got a file called `bg.class` because the `javac` command outputs a `.class file` with the same basename as the input `.java` file (in your case `blocktestgui.java`)

Comment: Remember that a Java file can contain multiple classes. The compiler does not default the generated class names based off the file name. It does require however, that public class names match the file they are contained in. And that there is only one public class contained in a single file.

Comment: So, in my java file, I changed my class so it reads "public class Blocktestgui"  It has the exact same name as my java file, so I now have a Blocktestgui.java and a Blocktestgui.class.  It didn't give me an error when I compiled.  My new question is how should my manifest read now?  I really appreciate the help and quick responses from everyone.

Comment: @Perception - true, I missed that bg was not public (making no class accessible to the outside world, .class or .jar)

Comment: So, just a quick question.  I do a file--save as--manifest.mf instead of .txt?  THEN run the jar cvmf?

Comment: Either way, when I get the jar file and double click...I see the console window pop up then close.  If I try to run it in the console with jar -jar it says "Unable to access jarfile"

Comment: to create the jar: `jar cvf bg.jar blocktestgui.class manifest.mf`. to run: `java -jar bg.jar` (*P.S. tested and working on my machine)

Comment: If you got it working on your machine could you please let me know what was in your manifest.mf?  When I get to the java -jar bg.jar it gives me an error of "no main manifest attribute, in bg.jar"
The first three lines of my corrected java file NOW look like:
`import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Blocktestgui {
public static void main(String[] args) {`

My current manifest.mf looks like:
`Main-Class: Blocktestgui`

Comment: Update your question so that all can follow please.  Include all compilation and jar creation lines as well as current code and manifest.mf contents.

Answer (score 0):

Moreover this is default manifest . . .
When you create a JAR file, it automatically receives a default manifest file. There can be only one manifest file in an archive, and it always has the pathname

META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

When you create a JAR file, the default manifest file simply contains the following:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)

These lines show that a manifest's entries take the form of "header: value" pairs. The name of a header is separated from its value by a colon. The default manifest conforms to version 1.0 of the manifest specification and was created by the 1.7.0_06 version of the JDK.

The manifest can also contain information about the other files that are packaged in the archive. Exactly what file information should be recorded in the manifest depends on how you intend to use the JAR file. The default manifest makes no assumptions about what information it should record about other files.